# Storing Encryption Certificate Name in Config File

Tags: c#, configuration, certificate, ssl-certificate, app-config

In my desktop application, I have a config file storing the database connection string.  Due to use of a windows service account so that our IT group can manage permissions through global group accounts, I've been asked to encrypt this string.  It looks like they are going to setup an internally accessible certificate for me to use.  Since I've got the config file, I'd like to place the Friendly Name or other pertinent information that will help ensure I consistently find the certificate in the config file as well.  Is this a bad idea?  I figure that it doesn't do anyone any good from the outside if they can't access our network anyways, even if they have access to the application.  And even if they do, there's likely other security issues with how they accessed it to be of concern.  But, I wanted to make sure that I'm not going against common practice or that there's not an issue I'm overlooking.

Here's my example config data:

```
<myApplication.Database>
  <databaseSettings>
    <database name="DB" connection="Development" certificate="AppCertificate">
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Development" connectionString="asdf0-sf089f7a980fdsafua0s9d8fjifa;fjksdafkjafpdsouifwepoqifjasdlkfjsdaf"/>
        <add name="Acceptance" connectionString="aksdfjas;fjpeoiufapsodifjnasdlk;fjweopiafjsdofnsdafipoweouwropqeijdfasfdf"/>
        <add name="Production" connectionString="sdafpoiewuioafndspfyqheosiafnsdaiofpu4we49fpoiasdjfsdaiopfhsdaivnwe9pwfas"/>
      </connectionStrings>
    </database>
  </databaseSettings>
</myApplication.Database>
```

Comment: You have your connection strings in there as well - which is an accepted standard. If someone gets hold of your config file your IT team will have bigger problems than having the name of a certificate in there.

Comment: @MattStannett yeah, and I'm not fan of putting them together, but I'm even more so not a fan of hard-coding the certificate name into the application.  Because if for some reason our IT team decides I need a new one with a new name, I've got to recompile and redistribute.  I thought about storing it in the registry, but even then it has to originate from somewhere which will likely be located in the same directory as the rest of the assemblies and data files.

Comment: I'm not sure what if any CI/CD you have but you could investigate XDT transforms ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx) as part of your build process, or applications such as TeamCity or Octopus deploy support variable replacement in config files.

Comment: @MattStannett After some internal deliberation, it looks like I'm going to split my config file into two (Local/Remote).  The remote will be stored on a file where basic users will have read-only access and will contain the connection string and certificate info.  Connection string will be  encrypted.  We will setup a global group for write permissions which the system will recognize as admins.  So this way I think we're creating multiple barriers both digitally and physically and killing two birds with one stone by allowing the group to designate administrators.

Comment: @MattStannett If anyone gets to the remote file, it's already too late.  So hopefully this is at least a step more secure.